# Issues accessing an array in JSON response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to access an array in a JSON response and receiving the following error:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Charts.Models.software]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

```
SoftInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<software>>(SoftResponse);

public class software 
{
    [JsonProperty("softwares")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string fixVersion { get; set; }
    public string vulnerabilities { get; set; }
}

<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)  
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.version) 
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fixVersion)  
    </th>
    <th class="text-center">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vulnerabilities)
    </th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {  
<tr>  
    <td>  
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)  
    </td>  
    <td>  
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.version)  
    </td>
    <td>  
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fixVersion)  
    </td>  
    <td>  
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vulnerabilities)  
    </td>  
</tr>
```

[Image of JSON Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccdgS.png)

Comment: Post the json please.

Comment: JSON was about 142k lines. Therefore, I posted an image of the structure instead. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you doing this class definition and deserialization right in your view?  What is `SoftResponse`? are you sure you're assigning just the pertinent section of json to that variable?

Comment: @RyanBrown - you could just post the structure. there are Json parsers online that can give you the schema.

Comment: @Rakesh I 100% agree, I was going to flag that comment as well. The JSON structure is in the image on the original post. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `SoftResponse` is an array before using either List... a JSON array is usually in the format of `[{softwares, version, fixVersion, vulnerabilities}, {softwares, version, fixVersion, vulnerabilities}]`. if your response is in the format of `{softwares, version, fixVersion, vulnerabilities}`, then thats an object not an array.

If one of your properties, like `softwares` is in the format of an array, make sure you use a list type in your class, like:

```
public class software 
{
    [JsonProperty("softwares")]
    public List<string> name { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string fixVersion { get; set; }
    public string vulnerabilities { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried this without any success unfortunately. Appreciate the help!

Comment: use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate an accurate model for your JSON

Answer (score 0):

Change line:

```
SoftInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<software>>(SoftResponse);
```

to:

```
SoftInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<software>(SoftResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the `SoftResponse` is an Array Json? Can you try to at least evaluate the SoftReponse first? Maybe the list of software is a nested property of the SoftResponse.

In Visual Studio there is a feature called **Paste JSON as Classes**.

[image: Edit > Paste > Paste JSON as Classes]

Copy the SoftResponse value by evaluating it using debug mode and use the `Paste JSON as Classes` feature to generate the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the attached image your JSON has a property `softwares` which is an array of `software`, so your class that you deserialize into should mimic the same structure.

Class that represents the Response

```
public class Response
{
   public List<software> softwares{ get; set; }
}
```

Class for software, the one you already have

```
public class software 
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string fixVersion { get; set; }
    public string vulnerabilities { get; set; }
}
```

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(yourJSONstring);
```

Now Response has a property `softwares`, which can be used to query the individual `software`